# The emulator process has terminated (exit code -1073741819)

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

**Проблема с запуском эмулятора на Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1**

Ошибка:

> The emulator process for avd has terminated.

Проблема возникла недавно, освободил на диске 12 гб, Android emulator переустанавливал.

Прилагаю логи, помогите пожалуйста:

```
2023-01-06 00:37:17,552 [ 466070]   INFO -Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_2_API_30 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300 <br />
2023-01-06 00:37:17,618 [ 466136]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Android emulator version 31.3.14.0 (build_id 9322596) (CL:N/A) <br />
2023-01-06 00:37:17,618 [ 466136]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - emulator: INFO: Found systemPath C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86\ <br />
2023-01-06 00:37:17,620 [ 466138]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - emulator: INFO: Found systemPath C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86\ <br />
2023-01-06 00:37:18,939 [ 467457]   WARN -       Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator. <br />
2023-01-06 00:37:18,961 [ 467479]   WARN -       Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\Acer\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_30.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading. 
2023-01-06 00:37:31,563 [ 480081]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appFileTypeManager took 11 ms <br />
2023-01-06 00:37:31,658 [ 480176]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=My Application, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=C:\Users\Acer\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication)RunManager took 18 ms, XDebuggerManager took 17 ms <br />
2023-01-06 00:37:36,024 [ 484542]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) <br />
2023-01-06 00:37:36,024 [ 484542]  ERROR -       **Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741819**  <br />
```

Comment: Пробовали гуглить по коду ошибки [`1073741819`](https://www.google.com/search?q=emulator+terminated+1073741819)?

Comment: Вот на это сообщение `Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\Acer\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_30.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.` обратите внимание.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=emulator+terminated+1073741819 - решение помогло

Answer (score 0):

В действительности, проблема была в выделенной памяти на устройстве. Меняйте Memory and storage на 512 и 64 мб.